# Radio button Value change not working in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
myApp.controller("MyCtrl",function ($scope) {
    $scope.value1= '0';
    $scope.$watch('value1', function(value) {
    alert(value);
     });
 });
```

**JS Code:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);    
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.value1= '0';

    $scope.$watch('value1', function(value) {
       alert(value);
    });
}
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<span ng-repeat="i in [0, 1, 2]">
  <input name="asdf" ng-model="value1" value="{{i}}" type="radio">
</span>    
<hr> 
{{value1}}
</div>
```

Alert shown on loading only. After that `value1` showing initial value only i.e `0`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sowvikroy/vo4vw8ss/)

Comment: You have to register the controller with your angular app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its actually the problem of scope. I've modified the example here at http://jsfiddle.net/ucf02Lxz/2/. Have a look. Basically you need to use an object to modify the value at parent scope.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    // an object to prevent problem
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.data.value1 = '0';

    $scope.$watch('data.value1', function(value) {
       alert(value);
    });
})

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <span ng-repeat="i in [0, 1, 2]">
        <input name="asdf" ng-model="data.value1" ng-value="i" type="radio" />
    </span>    
    <hr /> 
    {{data.value1}}
</div>
```

Read more at https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: I know you have the link there, but it might be worthwhile adding a short summary to the answer? E.g. This is a caveat related to JavaScript and not AngularJS: The ng-repeat creates its own child scopes which prototypically inherit from the parent scope. Any writes/sets to inherited primitive values (like string, number, boolean) on child objects will only set the value on the child object and not the parent object.

Comment: @ReinardMavronicolas You are absolutely correct. Thank you for pointing it out. I'll modify the answer to include more data.